# Date parsing in Go

Tags: date, go

I'm trying to parse a timestamp as produced by tar such as '2011-01-19 22:15' but can't work out the funky API of time.Parse.

The following produces 'parsing time "2011-01-19 22:15": month out of range'

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    )

func main () {
    var time , error = time.Parse("2011-01-19 22:15","2011-01-19 22:15")
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error.String())
        return
        }
    fmt.Println(time)
    }
```

Comment: I don't answer because peterSO perfectly answered but I'd like to precise that you're not the only one to find funky this American-centric date API. I'm thinking about making a tool helping produce those go specific parsing strings from normalized ones (ISO 8601 I suppose).

Comment: The time package provides standard formats: http://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Follow the instructions in the Go [time package](http://golang.org/pkg/time/) documentation.

> The standard time used
>   in the layouts is:
>
> > Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006  (MST is
> >     GMT-0700)
>
> which is Unix time `1136243045`. (Think
>   of it as `01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700`.)
>   To define your own format, write down
>   what the standard time would look like
>   formatted your way.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04", "2011-01-19 22:15")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(time.SecondsToUTC(t.Seconds()))
}

Output: Wed Jan 19 22:15:00 UTC 2011
```

Comment: note that you can't use just any year or month for the template, it has to be one from the standard templates.