# Golang: How to validate a MySQL timestamp string

Tags: mysql, validation, date, go, time

How can we check that a string considered to be a MySQL TIMESTAMP is actually valid? The format used is:

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.fraction]` where "fraction" has 3 digits.

For example `2016-03-28 12:17:30.022` should be valid. Preferably I would like to avoid regex and use `time.Parse()` but any other suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Call time.Parse with a layout string such as "2006-01-02 15:04:05.999" on your time string. If that results in a valid time.Time value and no error then you're string should work in the db. I don't use MySQL but between PostgreSQL and Go you can pass around timestamps and time.Time values without converting to strings... so maybe that simplifies your problem. Covert the string in Go using time.Parse and then write the time.Time value to the db.

Comment: Thanks @Snowman. This is exactly what I was looking for...

Comment: glad to help. I posted that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call time.Parse with a layout string such as "2006-01-02 15:04:05.999"
on your time string. If that results in a valid time.Time value and no error then your string should work in the db.

```
timeStamp, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05.999", yourTimeString)
    if err != nil {
        // do something with err...
    }
// do something with timeStamp...
```

I don't use MySQL but between PostgreSQL and Go you can pass around timestamps and time.Time values without converting to strings... so maybe that simplifies your problem. Covert the string in Go using time.Parse and then write the time.Time value to the db.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TIMESTAMP()` to convert the string to `timestamp`. If it can be converted to a valid timestamp, it is valid. If converted to `NULL`, then it is not a void timestamp string.

Use:

```
TIMESTAMP('2016-03-28 12:17:30.022') IS NOT NULL
```

## Demo

```
mysql> select TIMESTAMP('2016-03-28 12:17:30.022'), TIMESTAMP('2016-03-28 12:17:300.022');
+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| TIMESTAMP('2016-03-28 12:17:30.022') | TIMESTAMP('2016-03-28 12:17:300.022') |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2016-03-28 12:17:30.022              | NULL                                  |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select TIMESTAMP('2016-03-28 12:17:30.022') IS NOT NULL, TIMESTAMP('2016-03-28 12:17:300.022') IS NOT NULL;
+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| TIMESTAMP('2016-03-28 12:17:30.022') IS NOT NULL | TIMESTAMP('2016-03-28 12:17:300.022') IS NOT NULL |
+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                                1 |                                                 0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I want to do the check inside Go code.

Answer (score 1):

As @Snowman pointed out in his comment, one solution is by using a layout string and `time.Parse()`

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func main() {

  timestamp    := "2016-03-28 11:50:50.476"
  const layout  = "2006-01-02 03:04:05.999"

  _, error := time.Parse(layout, timestamp)

  if error != nil {
    fmt.Println(error)
  } else {
    fmt.Println("valid!")
  }
}
```

**Demo:** https://play.golang.org/p/6bcciN_OAb

 Also check: [Date parsing in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589636/date-parsing-in-go)